# Generate a dynamic Menu in my jsp from Database in JSP

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, jakarta-ee

i need to display a dynamic menu bar on my jsp pages depending on the user role (user , admin)

[this is my code servlet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kSTeT.gif)

[image]

[jsp code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zxNaP.gif)

[image]

my problem is when i click on the menu to navigate between pages, it displays

> org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: Better edit your post and insert your code snippets here.

Comment: did you consider using spring security, it provides you in built functionality to display content based on the role.

Comment: It seems some object in target page is referenced while it's null. Please, post full stack trace and more code of target page

Comment: rather than adding images of your code, you should include your actual code